# fopen() in S-Function: compilation error

Tags: fopen, simulink, stdio, c89, s-function

I try to open a file in a Simulink s-function with fopen(), but when I add the necessary lines it won't compile.
Here is the error log:

```
timestwo.c(84) : error C2275: 'int_T' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011bSP1\extern\include\tmwtypes.h(533) : see declaration of 'int_T' 
timestwo.c(84) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'i' 
timestwo.c(84) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(85) : error C2275: 'InputRealPtrsType' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
c:\program files (x86)\matlab\r2011bsp1\simulink\include\simstruc.h(897) : see declaration of 'InputRealPtrsType' 
timestwo.c(85) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'uPtrs' 
timestwo.c(85) : error C2065: 'uPtrs' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(85) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'InputRealPtrsType' 
timestwo.c(86) : error C2275: 'real_T' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011bSP1\extern\include\tmwtypes.h(500) : see declaration of 'real_T' 
timestwo.c(86) : error C2065: 'y' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(87) : error C2275: 'int_T' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011bSP1\extern\include\tmwtypes.h(533) : see declaration of 'int_T' 
timestwo.c(87) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'width' 
timestwo.c(87) : error C2065: 'width' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(89) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(89) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(89) : error C2065: 'width' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(89) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(95) : error C2065: 'y' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(95) : error C2100: illegal indirection 
timestwo.c(95) : error C2065: 'uPtrs' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(95) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier 
timestwo.c(95) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

And here's the code. It's just the democode for multiplying an input vector by 2 (timestwo.c) from Simulink. I guess the includes of stdio.h and stdlib.h are causing the error but i'm not sure. Is there anything i can do to use fopen in an S-Function?

```
/*
 * File : timestwo.c
 * Abstract:
 *       An example C-file S-function for multiplying an input by 2,
 *       y  = 2*u
 *
 * Real-Time Workshop note:
 *   This file can be used as is (noninlined) with the Real-Time Workshop
 *   C rapid prototyping targets, or it can be inlined using the Target 
 *   Language Compiler technology and used with any target. See 
 *     matlabroot/toolbox/simulink/blocks/tlc_c/timestwo.tlc   
 *   the TLC code to inline the S-function.
 *
 * See simulink/src/sfuntmpl_doc.c
 *
 * Copyright 1990-2009 The MathWorks, Inc.
 * $Revision: 1.1.6.2 $
 */


#define S_FUNCTION_NAME  timestwo
#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2

#include "simstruc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*================*
 * Build checking *
 *================*/


/* Function: mdlInitializeSizes ===============================================
 * Abstract:
 *   Setup sizes of the various vectors.
 */

static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetNumSFcnParams(S, 0);
    if (ssGetNumSFcnParams(S) != ssGetSFcnParamsCount(S)) {
        return; /* Parameter mismatch will be reported by Simulink */
    }

    if (!ssSetNumInputPorts(S, 1)) return;
    ssSetInputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);
    ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough(S, 0, 1);

    if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S,1)) return;
    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);

    ssSetNumSampleTimes(S, 1);

    /* specify the sim state compliance to be same as a built-in block */
    ssSetSimStateCompliance(S, USE_DEFAULT_SIM_STATE);

    /* Take care when specifying exception free code - see sfuntmpl_doc.c */
    ssSetOptions(S,
                 SS_OPTION_WORKS_WITH_CODE_REUSE |
                 SS_OPTION_EXCEPTION_FREE_CODE |
                 SS_OPTION_USE_TLC_WITH_ACCELERATOR);
}


/* Function: mdlInitializeSampleTimes =========================================
 * Abstract:
 *    Specifiy that we inherit our sample time from the driving block.
 */
static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetSampleTime(S, 0, INHERITED_SAMPLE_TIME);
    ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0);
    ssSetModelReferenceSampleTimeDefaultInheritance(S); 
}

/* Function: mdlOutputs =======================================================
 * Abstract:
 *    y = 2*u
 */
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    FILE * datei;
    datei = fopen("Test.txt","w");
    int_T i;
    InputRealPtrsType uPtrs = ssGetInputPortRealSignalPtrs(S,0);
    real_T            *y    = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0);
    int_T             width = ssGetOutputPortWidth(S,0);

    for (i=0; i<width; i++) {
        /*
         * This example does not implement complex signal handling.
         * To find out see an example about how to handle complex signal in 
         * S-function, see sdotproduct.c for details.
         */
        *y++ = 2.0 *(*uPtrs[i]); 
        //fputc(2,datei);
    }
}


/* Function: mdlTerminate =====================================================
 * Abstract:
 *    No termination needed, but we are required to have this routine.
 */
static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S)
{
}



#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE    /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file? */
#include "simulink.c"      /* MEX-file interface mechanism */
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"       /* Code generation registration function */
#endif
```

Comment: Try to move the line `datei = fopen("Test.txt","w");` after your declarations (i.e. right before the for loop). This is mandatory for c89 and your compiler seems to be strict in this regard.

Comment: That's it :)
Thanks for your help